# Finding $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{(0,\infty)} \frac{n \sin (x/n)}{x(1+x^2)}dx$ via DCT

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{(0,\infty)} \frac{n \sin (x/n)}{x(1+x^2)}dx$ by applying the Dominated Convergence Theorem for Lebesgue Integrals.

First, considering $(f_n): f_n=\frac{n \sin (x/n)}{x(1+x^2)}=\frac{\sin(x/n)}{(x/n)} \frac{1}{1+x^2},$ it then follows that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sin(x/n)}{(x/n)}\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sin(x/n)}{(x/n)}$. And thus substituting with $u=\frac{x}{n}$, we get that as $n \to \infty$, $u \to 0$. Obviously, $\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\sin u }{u}=1 \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n = \frac{1}{1+x^2}=f(x).$ Hence $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$.

Then the requirement is that $(f_n)$ is in $L_1$. I go on to argue that since on $(0,\infty)$ both $\frac{\sin(x/n)}{(x/n)}$ and $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ are continuous, then both functions are measurable. And because the measurable functions form an algebra, then $f_n$, their product, is also measurable. **How do we argue however that they are Lebesgue integrable?** I know, for example, that the Lebesgue integral $\int_{(0,\infty)}\frac{\sin x}{x}$ does not exist.

Also, I reckon we are going to use $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2} \in L_1$ to dominate $f_n$ such that $|f_n|\leq g$ for all $n$. I argue as follows: on $(0,\infty)$ we have $|\sin (x/n)|\leq|x/n|$ for any $n$. Hence $|f_n|=\left|\frac{\sin(x/n)}{(x/n)}\frac{1}{1+x^2} \right|\leq \frac{1}{1+x^2}$. **So, once again we get to the question of the function being in $L_1$.**

Finally, it is straightforward to apply DCT and get $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int f_n= \int f=\left.\tan^{-1}(x)\right|^{\infty}_{0}=\frac{\pi}{2}$. However, application of the Riemann integral bothers me somewhat, as we know that for the bounded Riemann integrable function, the **proper** Riemann integral is equivalent to the Lebesgue version. Does this application hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to check that each $f_n$ is Lebesgue integrable. To apply Dominated Convergence, you only need to check that $g$ is Lebesgue integrable. [Anyway, once you have checked that $g$ is Lebesgue integrable, it follows immediately from your inequality $|f_n| \leq |g|$ that each $f_n$ is also Lebesgue integrable.]

So how do you show that $g$ itself is Lebesgue integrable? Perhaps you could first verify that $|g|\chi_{(0,N)}$ is Lebesgue integrable for each $N \in \mathbb N$. [As you correctly pointed out, the Lebesgue integral of $|g|\chi_{(0,N)}$ is equal to the Riemann integral of $|g|$ on the interval $(0,N)$.] Then apply Monotone convergence to deduce that $|g|$ is Lebesgue integrable (with integral equal to $\pi / 2$).

Comment: P.S. Since your $g$ is equal to your $f = \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n$, the same method can be used to show that $\int_{(0,\infty)}f = \pi / 2$.

Comment: Oh, that was pretty graceful as an approach. Thank you, Sir. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but here it goes:

Define $F_n = \frac{n\sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}{x\left(x^{2}+1\right)}$

Then we have

$F_n = \frac{n\sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}{x\left(x^{2}+1\right)} \leq \frac{n\frac{x}{n}}{x\left(x^{2}+1\right)} = \frac{1}{(x^{2}+1)} = G_n$

We know $G_n$ is integrable because $\int_{0}^{\infty} G_n(x)dx = arctan(\infty) - arctan(0) = \pi/2$

So by DCT we get

$lim_{n->\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} F_n(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} lim_{n->\infty} F_n(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} G_n(x)dx = \pi/2$